# Please help me with formatting a string on same row

Tags: arrays, string, formatting, row

I am running into an issue with formatting a String in a row.

This is what I have now.

```
print(line1)
print("%20s"%"",end="")
for i in range(6):
     print("%-12.2f" %avg[i], end="")
print("%-12.2f" %sum(avg))
print(line1)
print("%-10s"%"","%12s"%"Ranks",end="")
```

Output currently looks like this:
[image: screenshot 1]

but I need it to look like this:
[image: screenshot 2]

I cannot figure  out how to have *Average* and *Total* before the numbers following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop you print the avg[i] values

```
avg = [1154.20, 1205.50, 1213.10, 1244.90, 1207.10, 1180.70 ]
```

Currently your code prints something similar to this:

[image: screenshot provided by the author displaying current terminal output]

To have "Grand Totals" printed at the start of that line of text, as indicated on your screenshot

[image: screenshot provided by the author displaying desired terminal output]

you could try to print the text outside of your loop, in fact just before it, normally this will require a new line of text, something you don't want and here is an easy way to avoid it - [Python New Line and How to Python Print Without a Newline/freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-new-line-and-how-to-python-print-without-a-newline/).

> The new line character in Python is *\n*. It is used to indicate the
> end of a line of text. You can print strings without adding a new line
> with end = , which  is the character that will
> be used to separate the lines.

I added the variable *line1*, and *avg* to your code, so that you can run and test it - as is displayed here, and I also added the line *print("Grand Totals", end='');*

```
line1 = "==========================================================================================="
avg = [1154.20, 1205.50, 1213.10, 1244.90, 1207.10, 1180.70 ]
print(line1)
print("Grand Totals", end='');
print("%20s"%"",end="")
for i in range(6):
     print("" + "%-12.2f" %avg[i], end="")
print("%-12.2f" %sum(avg))
print(line1)
print("%-10s"%"","%12s"%"Ranks",end="")
```

I don't have the rest of your code but my modification prints out

[image: screenshot of terminal output after the modifications]

If you want the text label and the first numerical value, closer together - you can change this line to have a 10, instead of a 20

```
print("%10s"%"",end="")
```

Results in:

[image: screenshot of terminal output after the modifications]

Hope that helps and feel free to post more of your code and I will have a look.